# Substance Designer and Blender

Tags: materials, export

So I recently purchased Substance Designer and developed a granite material for a blender scene. *(Below)*
[image]

So it's all fine, nothing wrong with the program, but how do I export it? I'm not expecting it to be native to the program, but I couldn't find a single addon for Blender to import a .sbar file. All I could find is how to export substance *painter* stuff.

So do any of you know how to do it without more paid software?

Comment: Export it as textures (image files). There is no way (afaik) to export procedural texture from SD to Blender.

Comment: @LukeD How can I export them as an image texture?

Comment: As far as I remember right click on New_Graph and Export, but don't take my word. I don't have SD anymore. Look on allegorithmic forums.

Comment: Use the Adobe Substance Designer Blender addon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXUe1aqWxjw

Answer (score 8):

Blender does not currently support importing packed substances (.sbsar files). Due to licensing issues, this may not ever be supported. In any case, you can just export the graph outputs as images and load those directly into Cycles. Note that .sbsar files are "compiled" to raster images prior to being rendered - even in renderers that support them natively, you do not get infinite resolution like you do with builtin procedurals such as the noise node.If your Substance doesn't have published controls or external inputs, and it doesn't look like yours does, there's not really much advantage to using a .sbsar vs image inputs. I wanted to clarify this, as it's a frequent misconception about how Substance works.

To export the outputs, right click the graph in the outline (the graph, not the package) and select "export outputs to bitmaps". Choose a path and check the channels you'd like to export. Official documentation is located here, if you need it: https://support.allegorithmic.com/documentation/display/SDDOC/Export+bitmaps

Once you have your channels as images, you can load them in Cycles and attach them to the Principled BSDF like usual. See my answer here: [Which is the best workflow to follow when texturing and importing textures from Substance Painter?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90981/which-is-the-best-workflow-to-follow-when-texturing-and-importing-textures-from)